# How to exclude single files when using MSBuild Scanner

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We are using the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild (1.1.0.0) and have a solution containing multiple projects.

There is a `SonarQube.Analysis.xml` in the solution root folder which we supply to the scanners cli.

```
<SonarQubeAnalysisProperties  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.sonarsource.com/msbuild/integration/2015/1">
    <Property Name="sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths">output/nunit-coverage.xml</Property>
    <Property Name="sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths">output/nunit-result.xml</Property>

    <Property Name="sonar.exclusions">Project1/Migrations/*</Property>
    <Property Name="sonar.coverage.exclusions">Project1/Migrations/*</Property>
</SonarQubeAnalysisProperties>
```

Now the problem is: `Project1/Migrations/*` seems not to get excluded because the `Base dir` is set to `.../Project1` during the scan. The same happens for all other projects in the solution. The result is that `.../Project1/Project1/Migrations/*` is an unknown path.

So what is the recommended way to exclude a whole directory from coverage and sourcecode analytics when using MSBuild Scanner?

Answer (score 4):

Try to put the exclusions in the project file (.csproj) itself, something like:

```
<ItemGroup>
     <SonarQubeSetting Include="sonar.exclusions">
          <Value>**/Migrations/*</Value>
     </SonarQubeSetting>
</ItemGroup>
```

See [Appendix 2: Configuring the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-.net-documentation/blob/master/doc/appendix-2.md#excluding-artefacts-from-analysis).

Comment: Thank you. This may works, but I don`t like to put SonarQube relates settings into my project files.